# How can get return message if a user successfully sign up in firebase for web app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

here is my java script firebase code

```
var username = $("#user_email").val();
var password = $("#user_password").val();
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(error);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: you need to add an observer `onAuthStateChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a best way to do that

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(function(user) {
  // User Logged In.
  console.log(user);
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only error code/message will be returned. If it is success, you can use below function to proceed further.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```